# Scraping websites with rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

This is in my lib/tasks folder in my rails app, for some reason I keep getting an error every time I try to run the task.

```
desc 'Fetch product prices'
task :fetch_prices => :environment do

  require "nokogiri"
  require "open-uri"

  Product.each do |product|
    url = "http://www.lowes.ca/search/#{CGI.escape(product.title)}.html"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
    price = doc.at_css(".fntlb").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
    product.update_attribute(:price, price)
    puts "Product #{Product.id} has been updated with price #{price}"
  end
end
```

The following is the error I get when I try to run this task:
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/vagrant/depot/lib/tasks/product_prices.rake:7:in`block in '

Answer (score 1):

You want `Product.all.each` not `Product.each`.  Although it's a little weird the error says it's on nil.

Comment: I changed it to Product.all.each and now get this error: rake aborted!
404 Not Found
/vagrant/depot/lib/tasks/product_prices.rake:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/vagrant/depot/lib/tasks/product_prices.rake:7:in `block in <top (required)>'

Comment: Odds are the URL isn't valid.  Can't really help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your Product variable

Change this:

```
desc 'Fetch product prices'
task :fetch_prices => :environment do

require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

 Product.each do |product|
  url = "http://www.lowes.ca/search/#{CGI.escape(product.title)}.html"
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
  price = doc.at_css(".fntlb").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
  product.update_attribute(:price, price)
  puts "Product #{Product.id} has been updated with price #{price}"
 end
end
```

to this:

```
desc 'Fetch product prices'
task :fetch_prices => :environment do

require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

url = "http://www.lowes.ca/search/#{CGI.escape(product.title)}.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
product = doc.css('CSS SELECTER FOR YOUR CONTENT')


 Product.each do |product|  
  price = doc.at_css(".fntlb").text[/[0-9\.]+/]
  product.update_attribute(:price, price)
  puts "Product #{Product.id} has been updated with price #{price}"
 end
end
```